# ANOVA or t-test?

Tags: anova, t-test

I am trying to compare differences in sites and years related to the environmental variables. For example, is there a significant difference in chlorophyll concentration (chlo) over the years (from 2002-08)? Or is there a difference in chlorophyll concentration between Seychelles, Indonesia and Brazil? I have started to use an ANOVA but I am getting pretty strange results, hence my query: which stat test would be best to use for the following set of results:

```
Year     Site     Chlo    DAC   PARD    SST
2003     Seych    2.95   0.24 -39.36   0.40
2003     Brazil  -2.35  -0.14  22.97   4.03
2003     Indo     0.42   0.04   6.82   0.60
2004     Seych    0.20   0.02  -2.30  -0.63
2004     Brazil  -0.22  -0.01 -10.28  -1.22
2004     Indo     0.32   0.03  15.82  -1.72
2005     Seych    0.20   0.02   2.02   0.36
2005     Brazil   0.01   0.00 -11.36   2.86
2005     Indo     0.28   0.03  -2.14   1.90
2006     Seych   -0.05  -0.03  -0.53   0.36
2006     Brazil   2.24   0.13 -22.89  -1.51
2006     Indo     0.41   0.04   3.70  -2.35
2007     Seych   -0.18   0.00  -4.49   3.03
2007     Brazil  -1.04  -0.06   8.85  -0.04
2007     Indo     0.15   0.01  -4.55   0.54
2008     Seych   -0.64  -0.05  11.52  -4.20
2008     Brazil  -0.26  -0.01   5.65   0.24
2008     Indo    -0.12   0.00 -16.04  -2.98
2009     Seych   -0.97  -0.09  15.65   2.63
2009     Brazil   2.36   0.14  -7.06   2.46
2009     Indo    -0.54  -0.06  23.97   2.68
2010     Seych   -0.08   0.00  -2.58   1.49 
2010     Brazil   1.20   0.07  -5.91   1.66
2010     Indo    -0.46  -0.04 -22.87   5.62 
2011     Seych   -0.62  -0.04   8.44   0.33
2011     Brazil  -0.13  -0.01  -3.38  -4.57
2011     Indo    -0.11  -0.01 -12.32  -0.54
2012     Seych   -0.81  -0.07  11.64  -2.65
2012     Brazil  -1.80  -0.11  23.42  -3.71
2012     Indo    -0.35  -0.03   7.63  -3.75
```

I have asked a similar question in the hope I will receive a clearer response from users. Is a one way ANOVA the correct test to use?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user3170629. Be aware that sometimes it takes a while before your question gets answered--even a couple of days. Please do not open new threads to re-ask the same question when this occurs; this is against site policy. I recognize that at least you deleted the old version, but this is still not the way to go. Since you are new here, you may want to read our [tour page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which contains information like this for new users.

Comment: What are your results? What is strange about them?

Comment: For instance, Chlorophyll with Site yielded F (2,27) = 0, p=1. I do not think this is possible unless I ran the program incorrectly

Comment: That F is not exactly zero, but it is very small, about $2.6 \times 10^{-6}$. The means are *very* close together compared to the variation in the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is simply that there are very small differences in mean compared to the variation in the data. None of the variables (nor any linear combination of them) differ much over Site.

My guess is there are one or more important variables not in your data set that are driving almost all the variation in the data, and without controlling for them (including them as covariates, or good proxies for them) you have little hope of picking up the subtler differences between sites -- and even if your sample sizes were large enough to get significant differences, you couldn't rule out that it was simply an association between those hidden variables and Site.

There are bigger differences across Year on some variables, but you probably don't want to dichotomize on Year, and given Year has an effect, you don't want to look at something like differences in Chlo on Site alone given there's a Year effect. You'd want to use Year in a model that involved Site. To fail to do so both reduces power and invites Simpson's paradox.

[image]

As whuber points out in comments, the `Site` means may have been swept out of the various enviromental variables (apart from the SST variable):

```
              Variable means by Site:

           Brazil          Indo         Seych 
Chlo        0.001    -4.163e-18     1.662e-17 
DAC     1.212e-18         0.001    -1.390e-18 
PARD        0.001         0.002         0.001 
SST         0.02       1.11e-17         0.112
```

What's going on? Have some of these been mean-corrected already?

Comment: Unfortunately this assignment is primarily looking into differences in the environmental parameters over year and site. An interaction effect may be possible however so this is something I may consider

Comment: It is apparent that all four variables are residuals with respect to their location means (up to a tiny bit of rounding error in the least significant digits).  These data are worthless for testing differences in means.

Comment: I don't follow: the means have been swept out from these data, so by construction each group mean is now zero (for each variable). All information about the original means is lost.  In a regression model *(e.g.*, `lm(Chlo ~ Site)`) that causes the coefficients for each group dummy (as well as the intercept) all to be zero (up to rounding error in the data). But this will be equally obvious to you, so I think I'm just not understanding your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a repeated measures ANOVA, where the between subject factor is country and repeated measures are taken across time. If the between subject factor is significant you can use multiple testing (i.e. pairwise testing with alpha error adjustment)  to assess between which countries largest differences occur.

Comment: I would guess that a random effect of time would be necessary in addition to the random intercept.

Comment: @gung I think there might not be enough repeated measures (9) for a random effect of time. Maybe a fixed effects model is better.